# Firemonkey: Display data like display on website with many pictures and texts?

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I want to create a mobile app to share food recipes like this picture
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDuXh.png)
there are more text and picture under each recipe.
I have do a research and don't know which control in Firemokey to display data like this.
Somebody master in firemonkey please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Did you ask the same question under the name `ErnestoCC` before? Please don't do that! Read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question, **especially** [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and all linked docs.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a web browser, check `TWebBrowser` (included with Delphi) or `Chromium Embeded Framework (CEF)` google for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a rich text editor component.

These are FMX components:

- [TMSSOFTWARE](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxpack.asp?s=fmxricheditor#features)
- [Delphi Components](https://delphihtmlcomponents.com)

Comment: Did you build any app using this control?

Comment: Yes, the TMS one

Comment: Yes, you can load HTML code directly or create the text programmatically. Both providers have trial versions, so download the files and see how it works yourself